# Cisco CM -- forward single user call after hours

Tags: cisco, call-manager

CM 8.6 -- Unity 8.6.

Our CEO wants calls to his extension to forward to the operator extension, after hours.
Do I configure the DN, the device or the user settings in Unity? None? All?

Can this be done for a single extension or do I need a new route partition and CSS?

The CM duties fell to me. I did not set up the system. I am figuring it out as I go.

Comment: I assume he doesn't want to just push CFwdAll, "0", and hang up when he's leaving the office?

Comment: Hmmm. That sounds like it will solve the problem; thank you. Do you know if it is possible to do this through CM? Since I imagine if he forgets, it will be my fault.